# How do I get a Task Manager to work, that always opens when CTRL+ALT+DEL is pressed, even when OS is frozen?

Tags: freeze, task-management

Title.

How do I make it, that a "task manager" open every time i press CTRL-ALT-DELETE?

And I mean under all circumstances, even when X11 shat the bed for example.

Comment: Ctrl-Alt-Del is a Windows  feature; it opens a fairly resource heavy window that often doesn’t help much. Linux has much lighter-weight utilities accessible from the command line: Ctrl-Alt-T to open a terminal and there are lots of tools to problem solve / close unresponsive programs or terminate processes. The issue with the Windows approach is that, when your system is struggling, opening a program with heavy-ish system requirements to troubleshoot it can just add to the problem.

Comment: & you might want to remove the unnecessary swearing to avoid this being removed for being offensive.